# c++ enum class must give all member a value or no value to ensure uniqueness?

Tags: c++, enums

```
enum class Status: char {
    test1 = '1',
    test2 = '10',
    test3
};

int main() {
    Status test1 = Status::test1;
    Status test2 = Status::test2;
    Status test3 = Status::test3;
    if (test1==test3) {
        cout << "Enum same"<< endl;
    }
    if (static_cast<char>(test1) == static_cast<char>(test3)) {
        cout << "value same" << endl;
    }
}
```

This snippet actually outputs,

```
Enum same
value same
```

That means if I mixed `enum class` member with set and unset, the compiler does not try to avoid giving the same value as other member? Apart from give a value to each member, any other way to ensure each member in `enum class` has different value?

Comment: The problem probably have more to do with your use of implentation-specific multi-character literals, like `'10'`. How could multiple characters be stored in a single `char`?

Comment: silly me, yeah if I changed to `test2='2'`, ti works fine, so actually the compiler has ensured member's uniqueness?

Comment: Actually no, the compiler doesn't enforce any uniqueness of enumerations. You are allowed to use the same value for multiple constants. For "uninitialized" constants the compiler simply takes the value of the previous constant and add one.

Comment: ***warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]***

Answer (score 1):

Due to the use of a multi character constant your code is probably (based on the observed behaviour, there is no guarantee that this will always be the case) equivalent to:

```
enum class Status: char {
    test1 = '1',
    test2 = '0',
    test3
};
```

As the value of `test3` is not specified the compiler simply sets it to 1 more than the previous value, in this case it'll use `'1'`. There is no guarantee that enum elements with unspecified values will have a unique value.

See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for more details.